# SDE linear combination of stock price

Tags: equities, price, sde, expected-value

Assume that $X_t$ is a process with dynamics $dX_t = \sigma X_t dW_t$ is where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. Given two deterministic functions $p(t)$ and $q(t)$, compute $\mathbb{E}[p(t)X(t)+q(t)]$.

**Solution**

Since $p$ and $q$ are deterministic we have
$$\mathbb{E}[p(t)X(t)+q(t)] = p(t) \mathbb{E}[X(t)]+q(t)=p(t)X_0+q(t)$$
where the last equation from the fact that $X_t$ is a martingale. To be more precise, $\mathbb{E}[X(t)|X_0]=X_0$.

**SDE dynamics**

I want to derive the SDE for $p(t)X(t)+q(t)$ using Ito's lemma. First, I am considering the case $V(t)=p(t)X(t)$, then according to Ito's lemma:
\begin{align}
dV_t&=\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}X_tdt+p(t)\sigma X_tdW_t \\
&=\frac{1}{p(t)}\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}V_tdt+\sigma V_tdW_t
\end{align}
The SDE that remains is quite straightforward to solve then with solution:
$$V(t) = V(0)\exp \left \{ \left(\frac{1}{p(t)}\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma W_t\right \}
$$
This will give a different answer for $\mathbb{E}[p(t)X(t)]$, so I am wondering where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just write $p'(t)$ for $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}$. Then your last expression for $V$ should rather be
$$
V(t)=V(0)\exp\Bigg\{\int_0^t\frac{p'(s)}{p(s)}\,ds-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\color{red}{t}+\sigma W_t\Bigg\}.
$$
This gives
\begin{align}
E[V(t)]&=V(0)\exp\Bigg\{\int_0^t\frac{p'(s)}{p(s)}\,ds\Bigg\}\\[3mm]
&=V(0)\exp\Bigg\{\int_0^t\frac{d}{ds}\log p(s)\,ds\Bigg\}\\[3mm]
&=V(0)\exp\{\log p(t)-\log p(0)\}\\[3mm]
&=\frac{V(0)p(t)}{p(0)}=X(0)p(t)
\end{align}
as it should.